# Windows equivalent of "> /dev/null &"

Tags: linux, windows, bash

I have the code below for running a code that uses mongodb in a .sh file. I am running my code in windows but I think these commands are for Linux. I would be very thankful if someone can let me know the equivalent commands in windows.

```
#!/bin/bash

base_dir="$1"
echo "Starting MongoDB..."
mongodb/bin/mongod --dbpath "$base_dir"/mongodb/data/db > /dev/null & 
sleep 10

echo "Starting Jetty server..."
java -Xmx8g -jar easy_esa.jar 8800 index &
sleep 10
```

Comment: These look like they are for Windows to me. Specifically, the usage of `\ 
` as a path component separator and the usage of drive letters strongly indicate Windows, since the path component separator for Unix-like operating systems is `/` and the concept of drive letters doesn't even exist.

Comment: Oh sorry this is for linux but I changed / to \ by myself as it was the only thing I knew about difference of linux and windows!I edit my question

Comment: Try `start "" /b mongodb/bin/mongod --dbpath "%base_dir%/mongodb/data/db" <NUL >NUL`. This redirects stdin and stdout to NUL. The `/b` prevents the child from allocating a new console. This has two immediate consequences. stderr will still write to the console unless also redirected; the program can block while writing if the console is in edit mode (e.g. from an errant mouse click if quick-edit mode is enabled). Closing the console sends the process a control-close event, with no more than 5 seconds to handle the event before termination.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows to run program in background is a bit diffeent. The best way is to set it up as service. Here is [short manual](https://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/) how to create service from program.

> Step One: Install SrvStart
>
> Step Two: Create a Configuration File for the New Service
>
> Step Three: Use the Command Prompt to Create the New Service

`/dev/null` in Windows is `NUL:` so your command will become:

```
command parameters > NUL:
```